# Network adapter connected to router but no internet access?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, internet

I have two network adapters on my laptop, one's a Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller (wired adapter) and the other is an Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (wireless adapter). They both came built in. The internet has worked fine until about a month ago when I couldn't access the internet even though both of my adapters were connected to my router.

The way I can solve this is by restarting my adapters, but this only fixes it for a few minutes until it slips back and I have to restart them again.

**Things I Have Tried**

- Restarting my router
- Resetting my router
- Calling my provider (they changed the wireless channel)
- Static and dynamic IP adresses (for both of the adapters)

Something you may want to know is that I use an ethernet PowerLine plug to get my wired internet 2 floors up from my router.

If you need screenshots or anything I will be happy to provide.

(Even while typing this I had to restart my adapters)

**Edit**

The strange thing is, when my internet goes "off", I can still use Skype fully as if the internet is still working. *What is going on?*

Comment: I would say, check this article first then respond back if this is not your issue.
http://tinyurl.com/p76xsmz
If it is your issue I will write it up in the answer section, otherwise I have nothing.

Comment: @Iraedei Okay thank you for the super-fast reply! If only my internet was as quick as that. I've tried that now and I'll let you know if it's done the trick in a few minutes.

Comment: @Iraedei Nope, sorry. Still the same problem after a few minutes.

Comment: Router firmware update?

Comment: @Watsche No idea how to do that. I have a Technicolor TG582n so I'll search how now :)

Comment: @Watsche So I had a look and the only ones I could find were Plusnet branded ones. Plusnet isn't my provider and I'm not sure what changing the firmware will actually do. Is there another solution, perhaps? I really think it's something to do with my adapters because all my other devices can connect (and stay connected).

Comment: Don't connect both at the same time... this serves no benefit. If anything, your wired network will be faster (1Gbps vs 54/108Mbps) and will take priority so your wifi will not be doing anything. What happens if you use just one connection at a time? What happens if you connect your problem computer directly to your router (not using your PowerLine ethernet)?

Comment: Oh, the other once can connect. Then it's really something wrong with your pc. Forget about firmware update. It's not the problem, if you connect with both adapter at the same time, windows will decide itself for one. It's not good, but its ok. But some router limit there connection by 8 or so.

Comment: @BigChris Right now I'm using one at a time purely because I can switch one off and the other on to make the internet fix itself quicker. And I'll try and do a direct connect now. I did actually read somewhere today that it could be caused by faulty wires so I'll change those first and then take it 2 floors down.

Comment: @Watsche After switching the cables I'll disconnect some of my other devices.

Comment: Okay so the cables weren't the problem and neither was the device amount. So I have it plugged in direct now so all I have to do Is wait a bit.

Comment: @BigChris Not even directly plugging it in works.

Comment: Both wireless and ethernet have exactly the same effect whilst directly connected to the router? You may want to try a friend's router and see if you can rule out a problem with your computer, or your router...

Comment: @BigChris Well I had a look at some more stuff (on my phone) and uninstalled some stock Dell crap like DataSafe and MusicStage. Restarted (while still directly wired) and seems to be working. Final test will be 2 floors up where this computer SHOULD be.

Comment: Seems to work fine now after uninstalling Dell stock stuff :D Thank you everyone for all your help :)